# ModX: TV images broken in file manager after port

Tags: permissions, modx

I just migrated my ModX install from a subdomain to the main domain. Problem is, the images being used as TVs are showing up as broken in the file manager (and the site). I inspected them on the server, and they have the same permissions as ones that aren't TV's and display in an image viewer.

Edit: Turns out the main domain converts all images to lowercase, so any image with uppercase letters gets broken. Not sure why it was doing this in the main domain and not the sub domain, but I ended up changing all the images to lowercase to fix the problem. If anyone knows why the server was converting the images to lowercase, I would be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your "workspace" path, it's in the database under modx_workspaces table. Also, are you sure the images aren't saved with a full path, or do the images work on frontend?

Comment: The images are all relative paths. I found out the problem. Edited above.